# BCB6 TListBox (How to get the value of multiselected items)

Tags: c++builder, vcl

How can I get the selected items in TListBox and add the items in the second TListBox, Im using Borland C++ Builder 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990115/bcb6-tlistbox-how-to-get-the-value-of-multiselected-items/5994664#5994664) said in his answer, you need to use the [Selected](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.Selected) property.

Here is a simple function I have used in several projects in the past.

```cpp
void __fastcall TSelectForm::CopySelectedList(TListBox *SrcLB, TListBox *DestLB, bool ClearDest)
{
 DestLB->Items->BeginUpdate();
 if (ClearDest) DestLB->Clear();

 // copy selected items from source listbox
 for (int Index = 0; Index < SrcLB->Count; ++Index)
 {
   if (SrcLB->Selected[Index])
   {
     DestLB->Items->Add(SrcLB->Items->Strings[Index]);
   } // end if
 } // end for

 DestLB->Items->EndUpdate();
} // end CopySelectedList
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the Selected[] property. if Selected[i]==true then Items[i] is selected.